# Add text in plot R

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile

I want to add information data in my plot, but it doesn't display the text.

I tried:

```
warna <- brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "RdYlGn")
warna <- rev(warna)
plot(pm10_mean, col=palette(warna), main="Rata Rata PM10")
plot(shp, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, add=TRUE)
text(x,y,"sulawesi")
```

it just display like this without text "sulawesi"

[image]

The plot that i want to save:

[image]

Any suggestion to get plot like that?

Comment: Maybe `text(..., xpd = TRUE)`. See `help('par')` for the meaning of graphic parameter `xpd`.